# How to parse headers as a string from raw text in email via imap?

Tags: python, email, parsing, imap, gmail-imap

I'm trying to parse the Subject line, To, From and the body text as a string via imaplib and email module. I'm getting an error message saying ***AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'*** when I try to parse the raw message. Please assist.

```
import imaplib

import email

Mymail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

password = input()

abcxyz123

Mymail.login('xxx@gmail.com', password)

('OK', [b'xxx@gmail.com authenticated (Success)'])

Mymail.select('INBOX', readonly = True)

('OK', [b'1'])

UIDs = Mymail.search(None, '(SINCE "20-Aug-2019")')

UIDs

('OK', [b'1'])

rawMessage = Mymail.fetch('1', '(BODY[] FLAGS)')

rawHeader = Mymail.fetch('1', "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (FROM)])")

rawHeader2 = Mymail.fetch('1', "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (TO)])")

rawHeader3 = Mymail.fetch('1', "(BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT)])")

rawHeader4 = Mymail.fetch('1', "(BODY[TEXT])")


**msg = email.message_from_bytes(rawMessage)**
```

I get the following error message when I try to parse the raw message:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(rawMessage)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/email/__init__.py", line 46, in message_from_bytes
    return BytesParser(*args, **kws).parsebytes(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/email/parser.py", line 122, in parsebytes
    text = text.decode('ASCII', errors='surrogateescape')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'*
```

Comment: Check the email and email.parser modules, they do message parsing nicely, esp in recent python 3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You are attempting to parse a tuple object to a method which attempts to decode bytes.*

#### More Information:

`imaplib.IMAP4_SSL().fetch()` returns a [tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp) and `email.message_from_bytes()` expects a [bytes-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object).

You have mismatching data types. Tuples are not bytes-like objects that have a method to decode them. You will need to handle this accordingly before calling `email.message_from_bytes()` or use another method such as `message_from_string()`.

Remember that if you do this, though, `tuple != string` and you will still need to make a data type conversion.

#### References:

- [IMAP4.fetch() - imaplib - IMAP4 protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html?highlight=imap4_ssl#imaplib.IMAP4.fetch)
- [Python tuples - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp)
- [bytes-like object - Gloassary Python 3.8.6](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object)

Comment: Specificaly, most of the imaplib fetch calls return an error indication, and then data.  "typ, data = Mymail.fetch(...)` is the usual idiom for packing this tuple, then you can parse data